# How to use go echo middleware?

Tags: go, frameworks, middleware

I installed [echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) via

```
go get -u github.com/labstack/echo/v4
```

Its package in `go.mod` like

```
module app

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/labstack/echo v3.3.10+incompatible
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.2.0
)
```

In `server.go`, use a middleware as

```
package app

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
}
```

It alert `too few arguments in call to middleware.Logger`.
Other [middleware](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware) also can't been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(middleware.Logger())

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello World")
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":9000"))
}
```

and in go.mod only just it

```
module app

go 1.15

require github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.2.0
```